# Glyph origins of the character 岁/歲?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I teach a basic class in Mandarin to kids.

They enjoy seeing where characters came from.

I will be teaching them how to express their ages soon and hence the character 岁.

Is there an interesting etymology or story behind this character ?

There's obviously a mountain in the simplified character. Something about harvesting crops annually on the mountainside ???

I can't find anything online.

Another question, is there a good research somewhere for studying the origins of characters ?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B2%81/7127435

Comment: Simplified Chinese is hard to teach/learn. Avoid it if possible, unless your environment is overwhelmingly filled with SC resources.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[餘](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1.1
[合集13475](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=13475&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
曶鼎
[集成2838](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2838&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
為甫人盨
[集成4406](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4406&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
效律20
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[步部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=65)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「歲」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)):  **/*s-qʷʰat-s/**, *motion of Jupiter* > *year* > *years old*) was originally comprised of semantic [「步」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=631) (*steps*, referring to *motion*) and phonetic [「戉」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5462) (**/*[ɢ]ʷat/**). [Jupiter appeared brightest to ancient astronomers approximately once a year in the night sky.](https://time.com/5602213/jupiter-visible-2019-how-to-see-planet/)

> 「步」 is comprised of two mirrored *feet* [「止」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=141), indicating the meaning *steps, walking*.

As a component of 「歲」, 「戉」 was sometimes variously corrupted into [「戈」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=127), [「戊」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=239), or [「戌」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=383). The modern form is from a corruption into 「戌」.

> All four of 「戉」, 「戈」, 「戊」, and 「戌」 depict different types of bladed weapons, so they're quite easily confused with each other graphically in older writings.

Comment: Why do you describe the reflexes of 戉 as "corruptions"?

Comment: @Wilson ["Corruption" is a standard academic term in paleography](https://www.britannica.com/science/textual-corruption) - something is "corrupted" if the original function of the graphic unit is obscured. In this case, 戉 is corrupted into 戌 in the modern glyph, so that the original rebus function (phonetic hint **/\*[ɢ]ʷat/**) is obscured: 戌 has sound **/\*s.mi[t]/** and meaning *axe-weapon*, neither of which have anything to do with 歲.